# npm5 package-lock.json different entries on different machines

Tags: npm, node-modules, package.json, package-lock.json

Our project uses npm for package management. After upgrading from npm 4 to npm 5, we decided to opt-in for the new `package-lock.json`.

After committing it and performing `npm install` on other machines, we spotted differences in the way the version and resolved entries are specified:

**1) example of package-lock.json dependencies with `version` encoded as `URL`:**

```
"jspm": {
  "version": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jspm/-/jspm-0.16.52.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-axhH4I8TGsm9JnzFiXSXmudnXS4=",
  "dev": true
},
 "systemjs": {
  "version": "https://registry.npmjs.org/systemjs/-/systemjs-0.19.46.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-wEV0szNfBSoOPHoA7kGIxuTB444=",
  "dev": true
},
```

**2) example of package-lock.json dependencies with `version` and `resolved` properties:**

```
"jspm": {
  "version": "0.16.53",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jspm/-/jspm-0.16.53.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-VvNR9JWUyJM+XgG2UUWsrr/PtZ4=",
  "dev": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
},
"systemjs": {
  "version": "0.19.46",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/systemjs/-/systemjs-0.19.46.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-wEV0szNfBSoOPHoA7kGIxuTB444=",
  "dev": true
},
...
```

In addition to having an ***unstable package-lock.json***, our build server is having issues when installing the first example.

Answer (score 6):

Follow this procedure to produce a stable version of the package-lock.json:

1. **delete** the existing `node_modules` folder
2. **delete** the existing `package-lock.json`
3. perform `npm install`
4. **commit** and push the **package-lock.json**

For the rest of the team:

1. **delete** the existing `node_modules` folder
2. **pull** the new **package-lock.json**
3. perform `npm install`

Deleting the existing node_modules before continuing is an essential step because the package-lock.json does parse ***existing metadata*** from the `node_modules` folder.
This means that if your node_modules folder has **leftovers**, they may get added to the package-lock's dependencies, even if they're not an actual dependency (anymore).

Comment: This worked for me (make sure to delete the node_modules folder and existing package-lock.json, if it exists, before doing `npm install` when creating the package-lock.json). But for the "For the rest of the team" steps, I needed to add steps 1a: Run `npm install` (without the package-lock.json and node_modules folder), 1b: Delete node_modules folder again and newly created package-lock.json.  Continuing with steps 2 & 3 to `npm install` then worked as expected.

Comment: It does not work for me. The team still gets a new package-lock.json file.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check in this situation on both machines that:

- your node + npm version are the same and maybe doing `npm -g update npm`.
- the npm configuration property [`save-exact`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-exact) has the same value on both machines. (otherwise doing `npm config set save_exact true/false`)